# Counter problem for individualised appendix sectioning (Destination with same identifier)

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, counters, appendices

I tried to individualise the sectioning of my appendix. I would love to have it sectioned like this:

> **Appendix**
>
> A.1 First
>
> A.2 Second
>
> A.3 Third
>
> B.1 Fourth
>
> B.2 Fifth
>
> B.3 ...

So far I tried to do this as following (complete MWE):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\backmatter
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}

\newcounter{subappendix}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subappendix}}

\stepcounter{subappendix}
\section{First}

\stepcounter{subappendix}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{Second}

\stepcounter{subappendix}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{Third}

\setcounter{subappendix}{1}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\section{Fourth)}

\stepcounter{subappendix}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\section{Fifth}

\stepcounter{subappendix}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\section{...}

\end{document}
```

This little hack does indeed work. However, it is ugly and produces
the following warnings:

> destination with the same identifier(name{section.A.1}) has been
>   already used, duplicate ignored
>
> destination with the same identifier(name{section.A.2}) has been
>   already used, duplicate ignored
>
> destination with the same identifier(name{section.A.2}) has been
>   already used, duplicate ignored

This makes sense since the counter `section` is always set back. The warning is not the only problem. Because of the multiple use of some identifiers `hyperref` does not correctly link the to the appendix sections.

**My question:**

Is there a more elegant way to obtain the appendix structure I need?

Comment: Ever heard of `\section`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the dedault and don't confuse yourself with self made trouble.

[image: phxKomaSectionAppendix]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{Animals}

\section{Wombat}
\section{Capybara}
\section{Mara}

\chapter{People}
\section{Donald}
\section{Daisy}
\section{Goofy}

\end{document}
```

---

Alternative:

[image: phxKomaSectionAppendixAlternative]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\addchap*{Appendix}
\refstepcounter{chapter}

\section{Wombat}
\section{Capybara}
\section{Mara}

\refstepcounter{chapter}
\section{Donald}
\section{Daisy}
\section{Goofy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this does not produce the results I want to have. If you put `\backmatter` before `\appendix` you do not get the numbering in front of the chapters. Your example results in: "Animals - 1 Wombat - 2 Capybara - 3 Mara".

Comment: Yes exactly, you are completely right. That is the purpose (and sole purpose) of `\backmatter`. You don't need it, you don't want it and it does harm.

Comment: Well, don't get me wrong here but how do you know I don't need it? It's a larger thesis. There is a requirement that I do need the Appendix as a chapter and I do _NOT_ need an A in front of Appendix. Your solution does meet this requirement.

Comment: @phx Well then, your thesis office does not know basic rules of typography. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Your effort is appreciated. And no, most people don't know anything about typography :(